# TDOA using demodulated signal

Tags: signal-analysis, modulation, demodulation, time-frequency, delay

Is it possible to find time delay of arrival using demodulated signals (of bandwidth ~200hz)? I have a setup in which I receive (multiple receivers, of course) modulated signal from a source. I want to find the angle of arrival of the signal. The signal is amplitude modulated. Due to hardware limitations, cross correlation of the raw data is not yielding good results. So I want to demodulate the signal, and then perform cross correlation using the demodulated ones. Will it yield good results? I googled it a bit and I can only find correlation calculations being done on the raw data. I was wondering that the raw data would consist of lot of noise and interference. So why not demodulate the data and then find cross correlation at least when the signals are analog modulated?

Comment: Why is the raw data given poor results? Signal processing is like computing, generally: GIGO (garbage-in, garbage-out).  You're better off getting to the bottom of why the raw signal is not working. The demodulated signal may let you do TDOA, however the spatial resolution you get will be much poorer... which may defeat any other improvements you gain.

Comment: I modulate my signal with a high frequency, due to which the maximum allowed seperation between my receivers is limited to a lower range than that is required for me. So I want to calculated TDOA using a message signal whose freq is much lower than the modulated one